# Update items on a partial composite key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I have a dynamodb on amazon server which I would like to add one column in a table for about half of the records

The table has a composite key and I want to provide the range as a parameter and I want to update all the records that only satisfies that parameter (regardless of the hash)

For the moment I have the following json files:

key.json

```
    {
      "ExchangeName": {"S": "TSX"}
    }
```

expression-attribute-names.json

```
    {
       "#S":"Suffix"
    }
```

expression-attribute-values.json

```
    {
       ":s":{"S": "TO"}
    }
```

the command line I use for this is the following:

```
    aws dynamodb update-item \
      --table-name stockInfoListCompanyAndTickers \
      --key file://key.json --update-expression "SET #S = :s" \
      --expression-attribute-names file://expression-attribute-names.json \
      --expression-attribute-values file://expression-attribute-values.json  --return-values ALL_NEW
```

It then returns me the following: "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema"

I understand that I need to add the hash in the keys, however, how I am not sure how I am suppose to do it so that it is not used to search for a specific value.

Thanks